# CSS : Background Image with Background Gradient

Tags: css, background, background-image

How do I add a url background image to the gradient and position it specifically?
Because the gradient is treated as an image in itself

### CSS

> background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #98cb01 2%,#60a822
>   100%)!important;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/

> Multiple background images is a cool feature of CSS3. The syntax is
>   easy, you just comma separate them. I find it's easiest/best to use
>   the background shorthand property so you can declare the position and
>   repeating and whatnot and keep them all grouped together. What isn't
>   obvious while looking at the syntax is which image is on top in the
>   vertical stacking order when those images overlap. The spec is clear
>   in this regard and browser implimentations follow. The first is on top
>   and they go down from there.

**CSS**

```css
background: 
   url(number.png) 600px 10px no-repeat,  /* On top,    like z-index: 4; */
   url(thingy.png) 10px 10px no-repeat,   /*            like z-index: 3; */
   url(Paper-4.png);                      /* On bottom, like z-index: 1; */
```

> It's like z-index but this isn't z-index, it's parts of one single
>   element.
>
> I think it's slightly confusing, since it's the opposite of how HTML
>   works naturally. If all elements have the same z-index (and are
>   positioned in some way and overlap) the last element will be on top,
>   not the first. Not that big of a deal though, just need to learn it
>   once.
>
> The big thing to remember is that if you were to use one of the
>   background for a fully opaque / fully repeating image, list that one
>   last not first, otherwise it will cover all the others up.
>
> Also remember that while multiple backgrounds is totally radical, the
>   fallback for browsers that don't support it is that it displays
>   nothing at all for the background, so be careful there. The best way
>   to handle it, as always, is Modernizr. They even use it as the demo
>   right on the homepage of their site (adjusted for clarity):

**CSS**

```css
.multiplebgs body 
{
    /* 
       Awesome multiple BG declarations that 
       transcend reality and impress chicks 
    */
}
.no-multiplebgs body 
{
    /* laaaaaame fallback */
}
```

---

So for your example, you could do:

```css
background: 
   url(number.png) 600px 10px no-repeat,  
   linear-gradient(to bottom, #98cb01 2%,#60a822 100%)!important;
```